# How to get the dynamic assigned heap address and malloc size with llvm pass instrumentation at runtime?

Tags: dynamic, runtime, llvm, instrumentation

Traverse the basic blocks to get the malloc size args and return address at runtime.
I instrument the printf() function at every call malloc() site in the IR and hope it can print the malloc size at runtime.
In the example, the size is inst.getOperand(0), the malloc size get from the scanf().

```
for (auto &BB : F) {
    for (auto Inst = BB.begin(); Inst != BB.end(); Inst++) {
        Instruction &inst = *Inst;    
        if(CallInst* call_inst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&inst)) {         
           Function* fn = call_inst->getCalledFunction();
           if(fn == "malloc"){
                /* do something to get heap address and malloc size*/
                // for example
                /* declare printf function */
                IRBuilder<> builder(call_inst);
                std::vector<llvm::Type *> putsArgs;
                putsArgs.push_back(builder.getInt8Ty()->getPointerTo());
                llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Type*>  argsRef(putsArgs);

                /* declare a varible and assign, then puts args */
                llvm::FunctionType *putsType =
                    llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt64Ty(), argsRef, true);
                llvm::Constant *putsFunc = M.getOrInsertFunction("printf", putsType);
                Value *allocDeclrInt;
                Value *RightValue = IntegerType::get(64, inst.getOperand(0));

                StoreInst store=builder.CreateStore(RightValue,allocDeclrInt, false);
                LoadInst *a = builder.CreateLoad(allocDeclrInt);
                Value *intFormat = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("%d");

                std::vector<llvm::Value *> values;
                values.clear();
                values.push_back(intFormat);
                values.push_back(a);

                //puts size
                builder.CreateCall(putsFunc, values);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

My test.c file contains:

```
int a=0;
scanf("%d",&a); 
p1=(char*)malloc(a*sizeof(char));
```

The IR language:

```
  %conv = sext i32 %29 to i64, !dbg !81
  %a.size = alloca i32, !dbg !82
  store i32 10, i32* %a.size, !dbg !82
  %30 = load i32, i32* %a.size, !dbg !82
  %31 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @0, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %30), !dbg !82
  %32 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([17 x i8], [17 x i8]* @1, i32 0, i32 0)), !dbg !82
  %call1 = call i8* @malloc(i64 %conv), !dbg !82
```

can I get the assigned size and heap address at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

malloc() itself selects its address at runtime (and some implementations guarantee that the return value will vary each time the program is run), so if you want to get the heap address, you have to replace it with your own implementation of malloc.

Getting at the malloc size is easier: If callInst->[getArgOperand(0)](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ab2caa29167597390ab2fc3cf30d70389) is a `ConstantInt` you have the size. If not you might be able to [fold it](https://llvm.org/doxygen/ConstantFolding_8h_source.html#l00046), but that's perhaps beyond your interest?

Comment: Hi, I think I did not describe my problem clearly and change the post.   
I intended to instrument at compile time and obtain the size and heap address at runtime.
can you give me some advice?